# Using Spherical coordinates find the volume:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

Inside the surfaces $z=x^2+y^2$ and $z=\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}$

I integrated over the ranges:

$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

$ 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

$0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$

I get $\frac{\pi}{2}(4\sqrt{2} -4).$

There answer is the same except a $-\frac{7}{2}$ instead of the 4 at the end. Obviously I'm missing a 1\2 but I seems, I can not find it.

Comment: How did you find the limits of integration? If you can draw the area you will see that $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{2}$ is wrong.

Comment: Have you been asked to solve the problem using spherical coordinates?

Comment: I actually just got asked to use either of the two

Comment: It is not a straightforward problem for using spherical coordinates, but it is a good problem to learn deeply spherical coordinates method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $z=x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $z=\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{2-r^2}$ intersect each other, you will have $$r=1$$ This means that $z=1$ and $\tan(\phi)=1$. So the range of changing for $\phi$ will be $\pi/4\leq\phi\leq\pi$. While typing, I saw @Mhenni did it completely, so I am ending. :-)

[image]

Comment: +Wow.Very nice.@Babak S.

Comment: Awesome graph!! +1 $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 2):

This problem is actually better suited for cylindrical coordinates:

$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_{r^2}^{\sqrt{2-r^2}}rdzdrd\theta&=2\pi\int_0^1(r\sqrt{2-r^2}-r^3)dr\\&=2\pi(-\frac{1}{3}(2-r^2)^{3/2}-\frac{r^4}{4})\mid_{0}^1\\&=2\pi(-\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3})\\&=\frac{\pi}{3}(4\sqrt2-\frac{7}{2})\end{align}$$

The problem with spherical coordinates here is that the radius is a (piecewise) function of the azimuthal angle, which makes the integration a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426635/doubt-with-bounds-and-integrand-of-int-02-pi-int-0-pi-2-int-02/426721#426721). The title of your problem asks for the use of spherical coordinates. You got the wrong integral limits. Note that, $ \rho $ (I am using $\rho$ instead of $r$) is bounded from above by two different surfaces. The sphere when $ 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4} $ and the parabolic when $\frac{\pi}{4}  \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2} $. So, we have

$$ V = \left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\cos(\phi)}{\sin^2(\phi)}}\right)\rho^2\sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta. $$

I leave it here for you to do the calculations.

that, for $0\leq \rho \leq \frac{\cos(\phi)}{\sin^2(\phi)}$, we used the equation $z=x^2+y^2$ to get . I leave it here for you to do the calculations.

**Notes:**

1) To get $\rho = \frac{\cos(\phi)}{\sin^2(\phi)}$ use the equation $z=x^2+y^2$ and the spherical coordinates of $x,y,$ and $z$.

2) The integral

$$ \int \frac{\cos^3(\phi)}{\sin^5(\phi)}d\phi = \int \cot^3(\phi) \csc^2(\phi) d\phi=-\frac{1}{4}\cot^4(x). $$

Answer (score 0):

This was a trick problem from the book, use cylindrical. Notice it said, "when suitable". They are not circles.