# Triple integral using spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The following function is given: $$\iiint_{x^2+y^2+z^2\leq z} \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}dx\,dy\,dz$$
And I have to calculate this integral using spherical coordinates. The substitutions are standard, I think, but I am having a problem with the limits. $$0\leq\phi\leq\pi$$$$0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$$ are the limits for the angles. I am not able to determine the limits for $\rho$ defined as $$\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$ I tried it with $\rho\cos(\phi)$ as the upper limit but it didn't work.

Comment: What's the center of the sphere?

Comment: [Related problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392122/using-spherical-coordinates-find-the-volume).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're given the region $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq z$, which by definition is equivalent to $\rho^2 \leq \rho\sin\phi$.  You can assume $\rho \geq 0$, so this simplifies to $0 \leq \rho \leq \sin\phi$.

Is that enough for you to figure out the problem?

Comment: @Artemisia: Just noting: "don't forget considering the proper Jacobian in the triple integrals.

Comment: Are you sure that it is $\sin\phi$? I am not getting the answer using that. And yes I did include the Jacobian. I am getting $\pi/5$ but the system says that's incorrect.

Comment: Well my logic appears to be sound as far as I can tell.  When I work it out, I don't get $\pi/5$, so you must have an arithmetic error.  I don't want to straight out give you the answer because it sounds like an assignment, but to help you - there is indeed a 5 in the denominator of the answer.

Are you sure you're using the Jacobian properly, $\rho^2\sin\phi$?