# How to calculate volume of a cylinder using triple integration in "spherical" co-ordinate system?

Tags: calculus, integration, spherical-coordinates

Lets have a cylinder given by $x^2+y^2=1$ which is cut from the top by plane $z=2$ and bottom by $z=-2$.I am having problem regarding the limits of ρ for the equation
 ∭ ρ sin^2ϕ dρ dϕ dθ 
where ϕ is the angle that ρ makes with z axis and $θ$ is the azimuthal angle. I know ρ should start from zero but should it end at(or its upper limit be) cosec(ϕ)???

Comment: You can use the technique in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392122/using-spherical-coordinates-find-the-volume).

Comment: you mean i need to split it up?? But here its just a closed cylinder closed by plane surface and not sphere

Comment: You have different surfaces. You have the plane $z=2$ and the cylinder.

Comment: Oh yes... Got you're point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you should have

> $$ V = 2\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}\int_{0}^{2\sec \phi}+\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{\tan^{-1}(1/2)}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\csc \phi}\right)\rho^2\sin(\phi)d\rho d\phi d\theta.$$

You should have plots to see what's going on.

Comment: @B.S.: I see. It was a typo.Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @B.S.: It is corrected.

Answer (score 8):

@Mehnni has nothing left for me just making a plot illustrating his post:

[image]

Comment: And a nice plot it is! +1

Comment: Ah thanks...wish i could +1

Comment: Could you please explain how rho = cosec^2 phi

Comment: Do you mean r^2 +z^2= rho ^2