# shperical coordinates limits

Tags: spherical-coordinates

how to write the limits for the integration in spherical coordinates to get the volume of

1- the solid inside  the cylinder 
$$r=  \sin(\theta)$$ 
bounded from above by 
$$z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$$ and below by  the $x$-$y$ plane, in the first quadrant?

2- the cylinder whose base in xy plane lies inside the cardoid 
$$r=1+ \cos(\theta)$$ and outside the unit circle  ... and whose top lies in the plane $z=4$ ...

3- the volume inside the solid 
$$z= 4-4(x^2+y^2)$$  and above the xy plane .

Note : I know that these integrals are simpler in cylindrical .. But I want to know  how to describe using spherical

I have a problem in writing the limits for "rho" in the above problems ..

Also I wonder if we have an horizontal plane bounding the solid from above how to include its equation in the limits..

Can we measure the angle (phy) from positive  z- axis if we have an horizontal plane bounding the surface?! I think the surface from above must have a shape like a sphere ..

So can I conclude that if I have shifted paraboloid or shifted cone or a plane bounding the surface from above , it is better to use cylindrical ?

Comment: I think this can help in problem 2  
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614969/how-to-calculate-volume-of-a-cylinder-using-triple-integration-in-spherical-co
But what about problem 1 and 3 ?