# Finding the volume using spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, spherical-coordinates

I am stuck on the limits of integration for rho. I tried `0` but that didn't work. Is this because I'd be finding the area under the $z=2$ plane?

Question:
Write a triple integral including limits of integration that gives the volume of the cap of the solid sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 8$ cut off by the plane $z=2$ and restricted to the first octant.

[image]

Comment: Check my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392122/using-spherical-coordinates-find-the-volume). Another [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614969/how-to-calculate-volume-of-a-cylinder-using-triple-integration-in-spherical-co).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  From the diagram, the minimum $\rho$ value is given by
$$\rho_{\rm min}\cos\phi=2\ .$$

[image]